# AngularJS - How to make SPA with multiple sections

Tags: angularjs, templates, routes

I have the following basic breakdown of my layout:

```
<body>
   <div id="left"></div>
   <div id="content" ng-view></div>
   <div id="right"></div>
<body>
```

I use `ng-view` in the main content to load the content dynamically through `$routeProvider` and `templateUrl`. However, the content in `#left` and `#right` also sometime need to change depending on what page I go to.

What's the best way to add/remove elements to `#left` and `#right` dynamically? I would basically want that if I load `/view1` with controller `View1Controller`, then if this view has extra components, then I can display them within `View1Controller`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this sort of requirement (without any extra plugins) you'll have to pull your left and right views out into their own view and set each route's main view to include left, content, and right themselves.

Example:

```
<!-- Core Html-->
<body ng-app> 
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-view></div>
</body>
```

**MainCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.defaults = {
    leftView: "views/view1.html",
    rightView: "views/view2.html"
  }
});
```

**Route /view1 and it's main view (call it view1.html)**

```
<div ng-controller="View1Ctrl">
  <div id="left" ng-include="defaults.leftView"></div>
  <div id="content" ng-include="contentView"></div>
  <div id="right" ng-include="defaults.rightView></div>
</div>
```

**View1Ctrl**

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('View1Ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.contentView = "views/view1/firstPanel.html";

  //Add some other functions to change $scope.contentView to say 
  //"views/view1/secondPanel.html"
  //You could also temporarily replace $scope.defaults.leftView
  //and rightView to show the View1 route in full screen so to speak. like so
  $scope.setFullPanel = function(){
    $scope.defaults.leftView = ''; //or something else
    $scope.defaults.rightView = '';
    $scope.contentView = "views/view1/fullScreenPanel.html";
  }
});
```

**Route /view2 and it's main view (call it view2.html)**

```
<div ng-controller="View2Ctrl">
  <div id="left" ng-include="defaults.leftView"></div>
  <div id="content" ng-include="contentView"></div>
  <div id="right" ng-include="defaults.rightView></div>
</div>
```

**View2Ctrl**

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('View2Ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.contentView = "views/view2/firstPanel.html";

  //Add some other functions to change $scope.contentView to say
  //"views/view2/secondPanel.html"

});
```

Now that you have the routes and views setup for default left and right panels you could setup a route for a panel with no left and right for example:

```
<div ng-controller="View3Ctrl">
  <div id="content" ng-include="contentView"></div>
</div>
```

**View3Ctrl**

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('View3Ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.contentView = "views/view3/wholeScreenPanel.html";

});
```

Hope this helps. Also it's important for "[scope hierarchy reasons](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-hierarchies)" to ensure the higher level "default" variables are saved on $scope.defaults so any changes in View1Ctrl or View2Ctrl to $scope.defaults will be properly update throughout all your controllers / views.

Answer (score 1):

I do not completely understand your requirement but did you take a look of the ui-router from angular-ui. Link: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/.

Btw, you can see sample app here: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/ Hope it helps.